# How to start with call cost app for android?

Tags: android, android-hardware

I want to design an application to display a dialog containing call duration and call cost after call finished.

In that app I need to:

1) calculate real call duration

2) display dialog after call finished

I don't know how to start, so any help or suggestion, please.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to look into BroadcastReceivers and check to see if there is one that allows you to register with the devices calling functionality. When you then get a callback, you can display your dialog.

Comment: thanks for your answer. actually, I don't understand what you mean by " check to see if there is one that allows you to register with the devices calling functionality" ? can you explain more, please.

Comment: Please check the following link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html